# Need help identifying the set for these parts green pieces

Tags: part-identification, city

Probably LEGO Star Wars, but no idea which set.

[image: LEGOs on a table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wedge piece is [43712pb023 Wedge 6 x 4 Triple Curved with Air Vent and Hatch Pattern (Sticker) - Set 7734](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43712pb023&name=Wedge%206%20x%204%20Triple%20Curved%20with%20Air%20Vent%20and%20Hatch%20Pattern%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%207734&category=%5BWedge,%20Decorated%5D#T=S&C=6&O=%7B%22color%22:6,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) and comes from set [7734-1 Cargo Plane](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7734-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]

The tubular brick is [6042 Brick, Modified Octagonal 2 x 2 x 3 1/3 with Side Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1398#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). It came in only three sets in Green, all from 1997, all from the AquaZone theme. These sets are [2160](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2160-1), [2161](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2161-1) and [2162](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=2162-1).

The other two pieces are too generic to be attributed to a specific set.